# Is it possible to get crash logs with in the iOS device itself with out using crash reporting tools , AppStore etc

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics

I am creating dynamic Framework and providing to clients.. I am also not giving my .dsym files to anyone.
And the client App has crash reporting tolls when ever crash happens will look into stack trace and find root cause .. this seems working fine.

But I want to know if is there any possibility that i can write some logic and get crash logs from device and store it in some tool ..

Where exactly crash logs get stored in device(directory )?
How and where crash reporting tools getting there crashes from ?
Is it possible to get crash logs if i use Hockey source code in my SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You can add this method in your AppDelegate.m file

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  
(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {   

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler); 
}
```

And then in the same AppDelegate file create a method,

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) { 

    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);      
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);    
}
```

Now you have the Crash logs from **uncaughtExceptionHandler** method. You can save it in your directory of send them to your server next time user opens your app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes if we use APP.. but how can I get it  from Dynamic Framework?

Comment: For Dynamic Framework, create a method in your framework which accepts NSException and you can pass that exception from uncaughtExceptionHandler method. Once you have received the NSException in your framework method you can call a service and upload data to your server.